# Why is the text shifted to the top left when I want to make it larger with <4>, for example?

Tags: html, css

I've tried a lot now and really don't know what to do next. No matter what I put behind it, it shifts to the top left. I hope you can help me. The text is just an example.
I want to make the sentences that are preceded by an exclamation mark bigger.

```
<div class="megadiv">

            <div class="LONGDIV">

               !Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen ("Bedingungen")<br><br>

                    Bitte lesen Sie diese Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen ("Bedingungen") sorgfältig durch, bevor Sie die Website [] (den "Dienst") nutzen.
                    Ihr Zugang zu und Ihre Nutzung des Dienstes setzt voraus, dass Sie diese Bedingungen akzeptieren und einhalten. Diese Bedingungen gelten für alle Besucher, Benutzer und andere, die auf den Dienst zugreifen oder ihn nutzen.
                    Indem Sie auf den Dienst zugreifen oder ihn nutzen, erklären Sie sich mit diesen Bedingungen einverstanden. Wenn Sie mit irgendeinem Teil der Bedingungen nicht einverstanden sind, dürfen Sie den Dienst nicht nutzen. Die Vereinbarung über die Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen für [] wurde mit Hilfe von "TermsFeed.com" erstellt.<br><br>

                    !Links zu anderen Websites<br><br>

                    Unser Dienst kann Links zu Websites oder Diensten Dritter enthalten, die nicht im Besitz oder unter der Kontrolle von [] sind.
                    [] hat keine Kontrolle über und übernimmt keine Verantwortung für den Inhalt, die Datenschutzrichtlinien oder die Praktiken von Websites oder Diensten Dritter. Sie erkennen ferner an und erklären sich damit einverstanden, dass [] weder direkt noch indirekt für Schäden oder Verluste verantwortlich oder haftbar ist, die durch oder in Verbindung mit der Nutzung von oder dem Vertrauen auf solche Inhalte, Waren oder Dienste, die auf oder über solche Websites oder Dienste verfügbar sind, verursacht werden oder angeblich verursacht werden.
                    Wir raten Ihnen dringend, die Geschäftsbedingungen und Datenschutzrichtlinien aller Websites oder Dienste Dritter, die Sie besuchen, zu lesen.<br><br>


                    



        </div>
</div>

CSS: 

.LONGDIV {

    margin-top: 3%;
    width: 96%;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 96%;
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 1.8%; 
    padding-right: 1.9%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.megadiv {

    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `.LONGDIV` class is `display:flex`, if you need flex display add `flex-direction: column;` to class

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the text you want to be bigger inside `<h4>some text...</h4>` and warp the other text inside `<p>text...</p>`

and delete `display:flex;` from `.LONGDIV

```css
.LONGDIV {

    margin-top: 3%;
    width: 96%;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 96%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 1.8%; 
    padding-right: 1.9%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.megadiv {

    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;

}
```

```html
<div class="megadiv">

            <div class="LONGDIV">

               <h4>!Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen ("Bedingungen")</h4>
               <br><br>

                    <p>
                    Bitte lesen Sie diese Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen ("Bedingungen") sorgfältig durch, bevor Sie die Website [] (den "Dienst") nutzen.
                    Ihr Zugang zu und Ihre Nutzung des Dienstes setzt voraus, dass Sie diese Bedingungen akzeptieren und einhalten. Diese Bedingungen gelten für alle Besucher, Benutzer und andere, die auf den Dienst zugreifen oder ihn nutzen.
                    Indem Sie auf den Dienst zugreifen oder ihn nutzen, erklären Sie sich mit diesen Bedingungen einverstanden. Wenn Sie mit irgendeinem Teil der Bedingungen nicht einverstanden sind, dürfen Sie den Dienst nicht nutzen. Die Vereinbarung über die Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen für [] wurde mit Hilfe von "TermsFeed.com" erstellt.
                    </p>
                    <br><br>

                    <h4>!Links zu anderen Websites</h4>
                    <br><br>

                     <p>
                    Unser Dienst kann Links zu Websites oder Diensten Dritter enthalten, die nicht im Besitz oder unter der Kontrolle von [] sind.
                    [] hat keine Kontrolle über und übernimmt keine Verantwortung für den Inhalt, die Datenschutzrichtlinien oder die Praktiken von Websites oder Diensten Dritter. Sie erkennen ferner an und erklären sich damit einverstanden, dass [] weder direkt noch indirekt für Schäden oder Verluste verantwortlich oder haftbar ist, die durch oder in Verbindung mit der Nutzung von oder dem Vertrauen auf solche Inhalte, Waren oder Dienste, die auf oder über solche Websites oder Dienste verfügbar sind, verursacht werden oder angeblich verursacht werden.
                    Wir raten Ihnen dringend, die Geschäftsbedingungen und Datenschutzrichtlinien aller Websites oder Dienste Dritter, die Sie besuchen, zu lesen.
                    
                    </p>
                    
                    <br><br>


                    



        </div>
</div>
```

`